# JQuery: How to uniquely assign a value to a single selector on a very large HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to JQuery, so please apologies if this is a dumb question.

So I have an order form. My Javascript does this simple arithmetic: price x quantity = cost.

```
$(".quantity").on('change', function(){
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
    var num = (price * quantity);
    var cost = num.toFixed(2);
    $('.cost').val(cost);
});
```

However the HTML order form has 35+ potential rows, each row having a "cost" input field.

I could give each cost field it's own unique ID however then my JS becomes a nightmare. However, if I simply assign "cost" using an HTML class or ID, then of course every row gets the same value, which does not work:

```
   $('.cost').val(cost);  // This gives the same value to every input field.
```

**Question**: is there a way I can assign it, with it only impacting the single relevant input field and without having the mother of all JS with unique ID's for each input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible solutions, but one easy way is to find the very next `.cost` element. For example:

```
$(".quantity").on('change', function(){
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
    var num = (price * quantity);
    var cost = num.toFixed(2);

    // If the next element is a 'cost' element
    $(this).next('.cost').val(cost);

    // or if the 'cost' element isn't the next sibling,
    // the cost element who has the same parent (e.g. same <tr> or <div>)
    $(this).parent().children('.cost').val(cost);
});
```

Alternately, you can use something like `data-` tags to determine which elements are related. For example:

```
// Tags like this: 
<input class='quantity' data-cost-field='cost1' ... >

// With javascript like this: 
var costFieldId = $(this).data('costField');
$('#'+costFieldId).val(cost);
```

Answer (score 2):

> However the HTML order form has 35+ potential rows, each row having a "cost" input field

Grab the rows, loop through it, find the costs. The 2nd argument in the `$` function limits the search to only its descendants instead of globally.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  var cost = $('.cost', this);
  // do stuff
});
```